# How to manage Fragment in FragmentAdapter?

Tags: android, fragment, adapter

I have a few fragments in PageAdapter which placed on other fragment and I need somehow to control their states, update some views, etc.

I have code which looks like below:

```
Fragment frg1;
Fragment frg2;

frg1.setHandleProtocol(this);

class MyAdapter extends FragmentPageAdapter {

public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
   return frg1;
 }
}
```

This is very simple snippet, but it should help me to explain. This approach works good by the moment when `Activity` will be killed and restored by Android. In that case `PageAdapter` re-creates new fragments by Object class and they won't have a old links and depends.

Is there any good way to handle this new fragments?

I have ugly workaround. I am just going through all fragments in `FragmentManager` and re-assigning their to the old links.

Comment: I have faced a similar issue. It is much more complicated that I thought it would be to control states. It was much easier to add the pager within the activity layout and control the PagerAdapter within the Activity rather than using a fragment to hold the nested fragments in the adapter. I ended up hiding and showing the the views based on the nav position. I would say that is the easiest and most reliable way at this point. Google has not responded to the issues at the point with that.

Comment: @EugeneH Thanks, but I will investigate this issue deeper, since I have a complicated app with many additional fragments on the main screen like sliding wallet, sliding profile and other ones. Also I'm using DI via RoboGuice so I have to solve this problem